# Domination by a $\sigma$-finite measure implies $\sigma$-finite

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\nu\ll\mu$ be measures on a measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$.  Is it true that if $\mu$ is $\sigma$ finite then so must $\nu$ be?

Comment: The construction is clearly true when it is known if $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite (by the Radon-Nikodym theorem) but I'm not certain about the general case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $\Sigma$ be its power set algebra, then if $\mu$ is the counting measure, it's true that $\nu\ll \mu$ for any measure $\mu$, but there *are* non-$\sigma$ finite measures on $\mathbb{N}$ such as

$$\nu(A)=\begin{cases} 0 & A=\emptyset \\\infty & \textrm{else} \end{cases}$$
Of course, this measure is very silly (and any example on $\mathbb{N}$ is gonna look very silly).

Alternatively, which I guess is also silly, for arbitrary $X$ and $\mu$, you can just declare
$$
\nu(A)=\begin{cases} 0 & \mu(A)=0\\ \infty & \textrm{else} \end{cases}
$$